# Use of * in Objective C Syntax

Tags: objective-c

I'm struggling a bit with some objective c syntax.  Can someone please elaborate on the usage of * in the following instance method.

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
}
```

I realize that we are creating a variable typed as UISlider and then setting it to sender once it is cast as a UISlider.  However, I don't understand what the * are for and why

```
UISlider slider = (UISlider)sender;
```

won't work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/.  The answer on that question provides a great deal of Objective-C specific detail as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*, like in C, when used in a type denotes a pointer (such as your case) and to dereference a pointer.

A pointer is just a variable that contains the address in memory of something else, in your example a UISlider object.

So in your example,

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
```

slider is of type `UISlider *`, or a pointer to a UISlider object.

The following tutorial about pointers in C also applies to Objective-C:
[Everything you need to know about pointers in C](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)

Answer (score 3):

All Objective-C objects must be referenced using pointers because they live on the heap and not the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a variable called slider that has type UISlider* ie a pointer to a UISlider.

You are assigning the value of sender which is anid which is a pointer to an Objective C object to the variable slider so that slider and sender point to the same piece of memory.

In Apple's Objective C all objects are declared on the heap and are accessed through pointers.

Comment: Just to make sure I've got it....

After

UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;

slider and sender would both be pointers to the same location in memory?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's important to keep in mind the difference between "objects residing in memory" and "pointers pointing to them".

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion arises from the use of (id) in:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
}
```

Objective C has an **id** type that is more or less equivalent to (NSObject *).  It can essentially point to any type of Objective C object.  So, in reality that above code reads:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(NSObject*)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
}
```

More or less.  Since we (the programmer) know that the sender object is an UISlider, we cast the object to a (UISlider*) when assigning its value to UISlider *slider.