# How to use the unary pointer operator (*) in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I'm reading a book called Java and C: Key Differences, Learn Objective-C for Java Developers. (my background is C#/Java so the concept of pointers and managed memory is new to me, so please bear with me)

In chapter 2, it explains pointers with this example:

```
int i = 1;
int *iptr;
iptr = &i;
*iptr = 2;
```

I understand the above, where `*iptr` is a pointer, it is assigned the memory location of `i`, also from the pointer `iptr` we can access the value `iptr` points to with the `*iptr` syntax.

Further down the book there is the following snippet:

```
//..    
NSMutableString *z = [[[NSNutableString alloc]init] autorelease];
[z appendString:@"Zombie "];
//...
```

From my understanding of chapter 2, the line `[z appendString:@"Zombie "]` should have been `[*z appendString:@"Zombie "]` instead, as we want the actual `NSMutableString`, not to its pointer, to be sent the message `appendString`!? I know I'm wrong and there is something that I'm missing, please point me to the right direction.

Many thanks,

Giuseppe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why \[object doSomething\] and not \[*object doSomething\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething)

Comment: I wrote a rather long winded explanation of this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Objective-C, you *always* work with pointers to objects (you can't create an object on the stack). Messages are always passed to pointers (although that's only an abstraction -- more complicated things are done at the runtime level).

Comment: Almost -- Blocks are both Objective-C objects and they start on the stack.  The real issue, though, is how objc_msgSend() is defined; it takes a reference to an object.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that the Objective-C syntax is not the same as plain C language.

Yes, an Obj-C object is defined with the normal C syntax since it's actually a pointer to a structure but is then used without the `*` operator while dealing with Objective-C instructions..

Actually nothing forbids the semantics of Objective-C from sending a message to an object through its pointer, so simply don't worry.

In any case this applies to every object but there are many `typedefs` (for example `NSInteger`) that wraps primitive o structured C types. They can be used in C either by directly working with them onto the stack, either by allocating them.

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  The declaration of objc_msgSend() -- the fundamental messenger in the language -- takes an object reference as first argument, hence the reason why the reference is used and not *foo.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are not aware that

```
NSMutableString *z = [[[NSNutableString alloc]init] autorelease];
```

is the abreviated form of

```
NSMutableString *z;
z = [[[NSNutableString alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Probably now is clearer.
As mipadi said, in Objective-C you always deal with pointers to objects and not real objects (like sometimes in C++ for example)

Answer (score 1):

The bracket notation `[obj message]` implies that `obj` is a pointer to an object. Thus `*` is to be expressed.