# objective c difference between functions and methods

Tags: objective-c

Is there any dramatic difference between functions and methods in Objective -C?

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between blocks, functions, and methods?

Comment: No, I was asking "is there any dramatic difference between function and method?"

Comment: Ok, so the blocks stuff in the question was irrelevant..

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First, I'm a beginner in Objective-C, but I can say what I know.

Functions are code blocks that are unrelated to an object / class, just inherited from c, and you call them in the way:

```
// declaration
int fooFunction() {
    return 0;
}

// call
int a;
a = fooFunction();
```

While methods are attached to class / instance (object) and you have to tell the class / object to perform them:

```
// declaration
- (int)fooMethod {
    return 0;
}

// call
int a;
a = [someObjectOfThisClass fooMethod];
```

Comment: @MByD, just a tiny point here, Python does have both functions and methods.

Comment: how to call function defined in other class?

Answer (score 6):

It is even simpler;   a method is just a C function with the first two argument being the target of the method call and the selector being called, respectively.

I.e. every single method call site can be re-written as an equivalent C function call with absolutely no difference in behavior.

---

In depth answer here: [Why [object doSomething] and not [*object doSomething]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething)  Start with the paragraph that says "Getting back to the C preprocessor roots of the language, you can translate every method call to an equivalent line of C".

Comment: that's interesting - can you show an example of that, and in which step it's converted to a simple function call? also, can you point me to some materials about that?