# What is the difference between an Objective-C function and an Objective-C method?

Tags: objective-c

Am reading the book "Objective-C Programming" by Big Nerd Ranch, and am not sure about the differentiation.

Context: NSLog() is an Objective-C function (not a method!) that works a lot like printf(). In NSLog(), however, the format string is actually an instance of NSString.

Comment: Duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672352/objective-c-difference-between-functions-and-methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *method* is just a function that is defined as part of a *class*. A plain function, such as `NSLog` or `printf`, does not belong to a class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "Objective-C function." NSLog is a function, same as any other standard function in the library, it just happens to take an Objective-C object, but those are just pointers so they can interact with C code just fine. There is nothing 'special' about NSLog.

A method on the other hand is part of an Objective-C class.

Answer (score 1):

Methods belong to classes & objects, and are invoked via message passing.  Functions are not attached to a specific class or object, and work exactly as they do in C.

Answer (score 1):

A function in Obj-C is not scoped to a specific class, whereas a method is scoped to a class.