# Why does the compiler complain about my simple function call?

Tags: objective-c

Just learning Objective-C coming from a Java background. I am trying to write a program that has no purpose other then to teach me how to write functions in this language and I am getting errors everywhere. The problem is since I just started with this language yesterday the errors make no sense to me. Here is what I have so far.

**Main Method:**

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString * prompt = @"Hello World";

        prompt = writePromptMessage(prompt);

        NSLog(@"%@", prompt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Special Method:**

```
NSString *writePromptMessage(NSString * prompt)
{
    return prompt;
}
```

**My Errors:**

- Implicit declaration of function writePromptMessage is invalid in C99
- Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
- Incomplete integer to pointer conversion assigning NSString strong from int
- Conflicting Types for writePromptMessage

Comment: Your function needs to be declared before `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Java, you need to add a *function declaration* (aka a *function prototype*) before the point where it's used.  A function declaration is just like the function definition, but without the body (i.e. the code) of the function, and ending with a semicolon:

```
// This is a function declaration:
NSString *writePromptMessage(NSString * prompt);

// This is a function definition:
NSString *writePromptMessage(NSString * prompt)
{
    // Function body goes here
}
```

In order to be able to call a function, you need to have written a declaration *before* the usage site:

```
NSString *writePromptMessage(NSString * prompt);  // declaration

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ...
    writePromptMessage(...);  // usage
}

// definition follows
```

Alternatively, you can place the whole definition before the usage site, but this won't always be possible (e.g. if you have two functions which can call each other).

C and Objective-C do actually allow you to call functions that don't have visible declarations, but this is considered a deprecated feature because it's easy to misuse and cause subtle errors:

If a function is called without a visible declaration, the compiler creates an *implicit 
declaration*:

- The implicit declaration takes an arbitrary number and types of parameters
- The implicit declaration returns `int`

So, what happened is that the compiler is assuming that `writePromptMessage` returns `int` when it first sees it, which is wrong, and that causes a cascade of other errors.  For functions which don't return `int`, you **must** never use implicit function declarations, and for functions which do return `int`, you **should** never use implicit function declarations.

Comment: So basically I need to do my delcarations first for all of the methods I will use in main. Then write my main method. And then write my method bodies?

Answer (score 2):

You either need to add a function declaration before `main`, or define the whole function there. As an example, this compiles:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void hello(NSString *text) {
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
        hello(@"Foo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And so does this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void hello(NSString*);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
        hello(@"Foo");
    }
    return 0;
}

void hello(NSString *text) {
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}
```

The compiler automatically notices Objective-C *methods* ([that’s a different thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982613/what-is-the-difference-between-an-objective-c-function-and-an-objective-c-method)), so that there’s no need to declare those in advance; this compiles fine:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void) doA
{
    [self doB];
}

- (void) doB
{}

@end
```

Apparently the compiler is not this smart about regular C functions, probably to keep in line with the C language spec.

Answer (score 1):

All these errors most likely stem from the same issue. It appears that you have not declared or defined `writePromptMessage` *before* your `main` method. In C (and Objective-C), you have to declare or define functions before you use them. The compiler doesn't know anything about `writePromptMessage`, resulting in your error messages.

> Implicit declaration of function writePromptMessage is invalid in C99

means that you haven't declared `writePromptMessage`, so...

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

In C, functions are assumed to return an `int` by default; since you have not yet declared `writePromptMessage`, the compiler assumes it is a function that returns an `int`, which shouldn't be converted into a `NSString *`.

> Incomplete integer to pointer conversion assigning NSString strong from int

See above (it's basically the same issue).

> Conflicting Types for writePromptMessage

Oh! Now the compiler *has* seen `writePromptMessage`...but wait. It already assumed `writePromptMessage` returned an `int`, and now it sees that it returns `NSString`, resulting in an error.

---

If you put the definition of `writePromptMessage` *before* `main`, or at least declare its prototype, à la:

```
NSString *writePromptMessage(NSString * prompt);
```

*before* `main`, you should be okay.