# Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99 iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, declaration, void

There are many topics like this but haven't find any which could help me.

my .h file:

```
-(void) function;
```

my .m file:

```
-(void) function {
   /*some basic switch statement for showing images in imageview*/
}

- (IBAction)do_the_function_button:(id)sender {
    function();
}
```

Where is the mistake? I'm sure it's something very trivial.

Comment: It is. Please read a basic Objective-C tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a method, which should be called like this `[self function];`, NOT `function();`, which is how you call a function.

There is lots of info about the differences between methods and functions floating around, here is one random post I found for instance:

[objective c difference between functions and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672352/objective-c-difference-between-functions-and-methods)