# using * on pointer in an objective-c function? (2 examples)

Tags: objective-c, pointers

i'm trying to understand this in objective-c :

in this example, indexPath is a pointer but we use it "as is" in the function : `indexPath.section`, instead of (for example) `*indexPath.section`(with a `*`) :

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (indexPath.section == 0) ? nil : indexPath;
}
```

so, in objective-c, we don't need to add a `*` to get the content of the variable where the pointer points to...?

but i found this function, where they use a `*` on the pointer inside the function (on `reverse` ) :

```
NSInteger lastNameFirstNameSort(id person1, id person2, void *reverse)
{
    NSString *name1 = [person1 valueForKey:LAST];

    //...

    if (*(BOOL *)reverse == YES) {
        return 0 - comparison;
    }
```

and for the `id` variables, they are using the variable name as is : for example here : `person1`

So, could someone explain me the differences between those 2 examples :
why on the first example, we don't add a `*` on indexPath,
why we don't add this `*` on the `id` variables, and we use it with `*reverse` in the second example?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing dot-notation with reading a structure. This is not surprising, since Apple made them ambiguous.

`indexPath.section` does not mean "the `section` structure element in `indexPath`. It doesn't even mean "the property `section` in `indexPath`." It means `[indexPath section]`. It just calls the method `section` and returns the result.

Similarly, `foo.bar = baz` does not literally mean "set the property `bar` to `baz`." It literally means `[foo setBar:baz]`. Whatever `setBar:` does will be done. In most cases, it sets an ivar.

Since `indexPath` is also technically a struct pointer, it is possible in some cases (but not always, and not often if you code correctly) to say `indexPath->section`. You should never do this. (There are some extremely rare exceptions, but you are unlikely to encounter them.)

The frustrating thing about all of this is that `foo.bar` might be a structure reference or it might be a method call. Without knowing what `foo` is, you can't know. This is one of the problems with dot notation.

If you find it confusing, don't use dot notation (it continues to be a controversial feature among experienced developers). It is never required. It's just a shortcut for the more explicit `[foo bar]` and `[foo setBar:baz]`.

`*(BOOL *)result` means "cast `result` from `void*` to `BOOL *` and then dereference it as a `BOOL`. It's unrelated to dot notation.

Comment: thanks Rob for this great explanation, i asked this question to Oddity, but maybe you have a good answer to it : if we want to call a method from the pointer, using the pointer is enough, but if we want the content where the pointer points to, we dereference the pointer with * , is it correct? why don't we do [*person1 valueForKey:LAST]; for example?

Comment: @Paul: Objects are messaged through pointers. In general, they aren't even allowed to be allocated on the stack. In short, you don't dereference them. It works basically the same way in Java and Ruby and many other languages — they just don't have special syntax for pointers.

Comment: You might find these answers interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void/1304277#1304277 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980

Comment: @Chuck : thanks Chuck, one thing though : BOOL can be considered as an object, if we do `(BOOL *)result`, isn't it? ( but if we use one of its method, for the different reasons explained in the links gave by @bbum (thanks for the links bbum)  we don't dereference them - i'm trying to make this clear to me :-) )

Comment: BOOL is never an object. BOOL is a char. ObjC is still C; you can take pointers to arbitrary types. But that doesn't make them objects. An object is a pointer to an objc_object.

Comment: @Rob Napier : thanks Rob, okay i better understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Dot-syntax on ObjC objects (pointers to objects) is a way of accessing methods of the forms [object getter] and [object setter: value], using java/c#/javascript like notation (object.property)  While the syntax isn't exactly consistent, object->property is already taken by direct property access.  reverse is just a normal void pointer, and so the (BOOL*) converts it to a BOOL pointer, and the * before it dereferences it.  id types are still pointers, it's just that the syntax for property access in ObjC isn't consistent with the existing C syntax.

Comment: thanks Oddity0x0, so if we want to call a method from the pointer, using the pointer is enough, but if we want the content where the pointer points to, we dereference the pointer with `*` , is it correct? why don't we do `[*person1 valueForKey:LAST];` for example?

Comment: [object method] is a shortcut for objc_msgSend(object, @selector(method)), the first argument to objc_msgSend is a pointer, and so object in [object method] must be a pointer as well.  I've never tried it, but [&(*object) method] should theoretically work

Comment: Note that `[object method]` is *logically* a shortcut for `objc_msgSend()`. It may actually be translated into one of several functions depending on the target, the types involved, and the architecture you're building for. This is one of the reasons you should not call `objc_msgSend()` directly, even though you theoretically can.