# Does the execution of Objective-C methods create "frames on the stack"?

Tags: objective-c, function, methods, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know that, in C, each function creates a frame and each frame is automatically deallocated when the function using it ends. Does the same logic apply to Objective-C methods? Do they create *frames* on the stack when executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they do.

---

Objective-C calls methods dynamically, so:

```
[someObject doSomething];
```

is equivalent to:

```
objc_msgSend(someObject, sel_registerName("doSomething"));
```

`sel_registerName` returns a selector, which is basically a method identifier, for the given method name.

`objc_msgSend` is written in assembly, and the code is available [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-706/runtime/Messengers.subproj/).    It looks up the selector in the object's list of methods.  The method list contains an `IMP` for the selector `doSomething`, which is a C function pointer to a function similar to:

```
void doSomething(id self, SEL _cmd);
```

`objc_msgSend` then [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#In_assembly) the function pointer,

So methods are just regular C functions, but they are called dynamically at runtime.  When `objc_msgSend` is called, the return address is pushed onto the stack and the CPU jumps to `objc_msgSend`.  It doesn't look like `objc_msgSend` touches the stack at all, so the method sets up a stack frame just as like C function.  When it's done, the method tears down it's stack frame and returns exactly as a C function would.  Since `objc_msgSend` left the stack untouched, it returns directly to the code which called the method, exactly as if the method implementation was directly called.

Comment: Good, succinct, answer.   There is a not so succinct answer (with a ton more information) here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980.  I **think** it is possible for an optimization to yield a tail call to `objc_msgSend` which would effectively make a frame "disappear" from the stack, but I don't remember if that is even possible on modern architectures.

Comment: @bbum Yes, clang generates tail calls to `objc_msgSend` .

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks.  So many architectures.... so many compilers.... so many years. :)