# Is [self class] special in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I ran across some code today that does the following:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBlah:(Blah)blah {
  NSLog(@"Initialising instance of %@", [self class]);

  if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
    // blargh
  }
  return self;
}
```

Now, this seems weird because self is used in `[self class]` before it's actually set a few lines later, but never seems to crash here and the compiler doesn't squawk, and it actually works.

Is `[self class]` treated specially by the objc compiler and just statically evaluates to the Class object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  Nothing special about.

`self` is actually set on entry to the body of the method.  But `[super init` *might* return a different instance, hence the re-assignment.   So, *technically*, that log statement *could* log something that is no longer true by the end of the initializer.

You'll probably want to read this:

[Why [object doSomething] and not [*object doSomething]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980)

Answer (score 6):

`[self class]` is not treated specially by the compiler. It is a normal message send.

Constructing an object in Objective-C on Apple platforms looks like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

There are two steps: `alloc` and `init`.

First, you allocate the object's heap storage by sending the `alloc` message to the class object.  Almost all class objects simply inherit the `alloc` method of `NSObject`. This method allocates the heap storage using `malloc` (or something like it), fills the storage with zeros, and sets the `isa` Instance variable of the object to point at itself (the class object that received the `alloc` method).

Second, you ask the newly created object to initialize itself by sending it an `init` message. Unlike `alloc`, `init` is very often overridden, or classes provide a class-specific initialization message (like your `initWithBlah:`).

By the time an object receives an `init`-type message, its `isa` instance variable has already been set to point at its class object and all its other instances variables have been set to zero.

When a normal object receives a `class` message, it simply returns the class referenced by its `isa`.

I'm simplifying here, because the modern Objective-C runtime supports something called [“non-pointer isa”](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html), where other things are encoded in the `isa` field in addition to the class pointer, so the `class` method has to do a little more work to get the class pointer from the field. But the `isa` field is still initialized by `alloc`.

There's also something called [tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html) where the object's class is embedded in directly in the object reference.  For these objects, `class` works differently, but only a small number of system classes uses tagged pointers, so tagged pointers never affect the way `class` works for your own user-defined classes.